# Wireshark to capture all IP devices on a network

Tags: networking, wireshark, sniffing

I have a Windows PC with hardwired Ethernet and two wireless Linux devices on a LAN.  My Wireless router is an Asus RT-AC68U.

The Windows PC is running Wireshark.

I would like to capture **all** network traffic between the two Linux devices.

All I can appear to capture are broadcasts.

How can I capture direct requests from one of the Linux devices to the other Linux device?

Comment: Since you are on a modern Switched or Wifi network, you can only observe that traffic from one of the linux boxes. The alternatives for capturing it remotely are very advanced, and almost certianly require purchasing hardware. Save yourself the trouble and do your cap from one of the linuxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ethernet ports on the Asus RT-AC68U must be *switch* ports, so a device connected to any of those ports will see only traffic directed to it and broadcasts, therefore your sniffing device must be on the Wireless LAN and the WLAN NIC must be in monitor mode.

Monitor mode on Windows depends on the NIC driver and is only supported with a few WLAN NICs on Windows

Comment: Not just that, but the wireless AP _itself_ can be considered a separate "switch" – it knows which MAC addresses belong to wireless stations, so those requests never even reach the Ethernet switch.

Comment: I was thinking that might be the case, but wan't positive.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

As @jcbermu said, your router's ports are like a switch, and switched networks only send replies to the "correct" port rather than flooding the entire net. (In this case they aren't even sent to Ethernet at all, but reflected by the Wi-Fi AP.)

So you'll have to trick the Linux devices to associate each other's IP addresses with *your* MAC address. If you manage them, it can be done on the device itself, by deleting the automatic ARP cache entries with `ip neigh` and adding fake static ones.

If you cannot do that, another method is [ARP spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing), where your computer sends fake ARP replies claiming that it owns both Linux devices' IP addresses, gets sent the packets, and reflects them back to the right MAC address. It's a feature in some sniffers such as Ettercap or Cain&Abel, but as long as they're running you should be able to use Wireshark as well.

Note that most network admins won't take kindly to active attacks. Keep it to your home LAN.

Comment: Thanks Gawity.  Yep, being used on my home network.  You think doing so will make the Wireshark captures different?  Also, didn't know whether there was a way to configure the switch to also send traffic meant for a given IP to another.

Comment: @user1032531, yes you can configure enterprise grade switches to send all traffic out a "Mirrored" port, but port mirroring is a blunt instrument (its all traffic, not just the traffic between the two servers), requires two nic's on the monitoring station (you can't use a mirrored port as a normal one, so you need two) and unless the switch is very high end, Mirroring is a best-effort function, which misses some packets when the switch is approaching capacity. Also note that ARP spoofing can interrupt the very traffic flow you are attempting to capture.